# Move-semantics with a member std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, move-constructor

Sorry if this has been asked before, but as I understand it, in C++11, `std::vector` has a move constructor so that copies cost hardly anything in certain situations, like returning one by value. However, if I have a class like this, with a `vector` as a member variable:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() { }
    MyClass(const MyClass& rhs) { }

    // other interfaces

private:
    std::vector<int> myvec;

    // implementation
};
```

And have a function which returns one of these by value, such as

```
MyClass somefunc() {
    MyClass mc;
    // fill mc.myvec with thousands (maybe even millions) of ints
    return mc;
}
```

Will the move constructor of `mc.myvec` be called and the move constructor of `std::vector` taken advantage of even though `MyClass` itself doesn't know anything about move constructors? Or will the copy constructor of `vector` be called and all those thousands (maybe even millions) of `int`s have to be copied one by one?

Comment: Better yet, the copy would be elided by any modern compiler that implements NRVO.

Comment: @K-ballo: Depends what the caller writes. If it's `MyClass mc; /* other code */ if (something) { mc = somefunc(); } else { mc = someotherfunc(); }`, or otherwise uses the return value of the function as the RHS of an assignment, then NRVO doesn't prevent the copy assignment. If you're going to write functions that rely on NRVO for basic efficiency, you need to make sure that the class either moves efficiently or can be efficiently swapped, to catch cases where NRVO is not applicable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you don't write any explicit copy or move constructors or any copy or move assignment operators or a destructor, then the default-provided move-constructor moves elements one-by-one. For details, see 12.8.9.

Since you define your own copy constructor, you will not get a move constructor by default. Either define one (perhaps `= default`), or get rid of the explicit copy constructor.

Well-composed classes shouldn't usually need any custom Big Five, and instead rely on members providing them and use the default version.

Comment: So the default-provided move-constructor calls the move constructors of all the member variables?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Yes, indeed. You can try it out by making a class that contains a `unique_ptr` and initialize it from a function that returns the class by value, that should work.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much for the quick answer and clarification. I will accept this answer when the time limit expires.